# Rails Rich Text (Trix) return NoMethodError: undefined method `render' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, trix

When I try to run a **rake task**, Trix return this error `NoMethodError: undefined method "render" for nil:NilClass` in this file:

```
/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0/lib/action_text/content.rb:91:in `to_rendered_html_with_layout'
/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0/lib/action_text/content.rb:95:in `to_s'
/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.0/app/models/action_text/rich_text.rb:12:in `to_s'
```

In console, in development environment, when I request a model instance and get `model.content` works. But, **when I request this in rake task (paused by byebug or printing with puts) I get this error: `*Error in evaluation*`**.

**In normal runnig everything is working**, same for `rails console`. This error shows only in rake task, even though I just fetching the model from the database and trying to call `model.content`.

`model.content` is not blank.